# Bouncy Castle Configuration for TLS

Tags: java, ssl, encryption, bouncycastle

I am using a test app that used java for TLS communication. Standard Oracle java is installed in my system.

I need to use the `TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CCM` cipher suite, which is not supported by standard Java, so many suggested using Bouncy Castle. I downloaded and copied the `bcprov-ext-jdk18on-171.jar` to  `$JAVA_HOME/lib` folder.
Also, updated `java.security` file to include Bouncy Castle in the provider list as below:

```
security.provider.4=org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider
```

I still cannot get `TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CCM` to work though.

Are the steps I did sufficient and correct? Can someone suggest the steps to install and configure Bouncy Castle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `BouncyCastleProvider` adds cryptographic algorithms such as the AES in the CCM mode of operation to the available algorithms of `Cipher` and other classes. As CCM is not included by default in Java, you will need to register this provider through code (i.e. `Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider)`) or adding it into the `java.security` file (as demonstrated in the question). You will probably want to add it to the end of the provider list as the algorithms of the Oracle provider are generally better tested and may be sped up using hardware acceleration.

However, the `BouncyCastleProvider` does *not* contain an implementation of the TLS protocol. You'd need to register the `BouncyCastleJsseProvider` for that instead. This is required as the Java TLS implementation won't magically know how to use the CCM implementation within Bouncy Castle. JSSE is an acronym of the Java Secure Socket Extension.

You can add that provider at the start of the providers so you know for sure that this provider is used for implementing TLS:

```
Security.insertProviderAt(new rg.bouncycastle.jsse.provider.BouncyCastleJsseProvider(), 1);
```

And you can also directly register it in the `java.security` file.

Note that the JSSE provider doesn't provide implementations such as RSA or AES for `Cipher` or `Signature` so it should not be in the way.

Comment: Or configure `org.bouncycastle.jsse.provider.BouncyCastleJsseProvider` in the java.security file, but **in either case you need `bctls-$version.jar`** _in addition_ to bcprov, because I'm pretty sure you _do_ need the JCE provider to get CCM primitive.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Yeah, right. I probably mistyped when searching for that .jar file, as I did look at the downloads page.

Comment: (1) Downloaded and added files bcprov-$version.jar and bctls-$version.jar to %JAVA_HOME%\lib\ext path.  
(2) Updated java.security file with security.provider.N=org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleJsseProvider 
(3) Updated java.security file with security.provider.(N+1)=org.bouncycastle.jsse.provider.BouncyCastleJsseProvider    
The tool now gave below error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bouncycastle/asn1/eac/EACObjectIdentifiers
        at org.bouncycastle.tls.TlsUtils.createCertSigAlgOIDs(Unknown Source)
So added bcutil-$version.jar also folder.

Comment: Thanks a ton @dave_thompson_085 and Maarten Bodewes